# automatic slide show does not work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to have an Slideshow on a html page and found a html/javascript code on W3 site and copied it. But it does not work. All I got was the 3 images shown as a list. I have been looking at some anwsers given here about the subject but still I cannot find out what the problem is. I thought that the code was complete and ready to go. So please I need some help.
The code is as follow:

the javascript
    
    // Automatic Slideshow - change image every 3 seconds
    var slideIndex = 0;
    showSlides();

```
function showSlides() {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex> slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(showSlides, 3000); 
}
the html
<!-- Slide Show section showing 3 img every 3 sec-->
    <div class="slideshow-container">
    <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img class="mySlides" src="../images/Icons/sa.png" alt="a" 
    style="width:100%">
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img class="mySlides" src="../images/images/b.jpg" alt="b"
    style="width:100%" >
    </div>
    <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img class="mySlides" src="../images/images
     /c.jpg" alt="c"                  
    style="width:100%">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the CSS the styling is a big part of making it work. Here is a link to the full code:

http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow_auto

```
<style>
* {box-sizing:border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana,sans-serif;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .text {font-size: 11px}
}
</style>
```

Comment: Hello Amanda, sorry I was not complete in my question. I do have the CSS styling and I am only using the body selector and values because I dont need a caption or the dots. The other solution given by a fellow "Stacker" did not solve the problem eighter. I think the best think is to copy the whole thing as is in a seperate html file and see if it works then. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

The only problem with your code is that you have the same class for `<img>` and `<div>` tags, remove `class="mySlides"` from your `<img>` tags and your slider will work well.

Comment: Hello, if I am not wrong the div and img tag are different. The div is mySlides fade and the img mySlides.

Comment: But I did what you suggested but still it does not work.

Comment: Hi Ncherel, thank you for your effert! I tested you suggestion and still I am getting the same result. No slideshow and the images are shown as a list. So there is something wrong elsewhere and not with the code. I think I wlll leave this nice script for when I have more knowledge and can analyse it beter. Thank you anyway!.